# After installing 'mesa', Ubuntu doesn't start up

Tags: 12.04, xorg, mesa, scilab

Firstly, i've deleted `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

And then tried below command to install `mesa` on Ubuntu 12.04.2.

```
sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa && sudo apt-get install libosmesa6
```

After reboot computer, Ubuntu doesn't start up ! (stay on Black Screen)

What am i doing wrong And how fix it ?

---

Edit (More information) :

[Sorry my English is not fine]

I'm using scilab. When i do some operations like `plot` , Scilab was crashed. For solving this problem , i did all things in [this link](http://wiki.scilab.org/Graphical%20issues%20with%20Scilab%205.X)

According to following part of [above link](http://wiki.scilab.org/Graphical%20issues%20with%20Scilab%205.X),

> Likely, there is a workaround to tackle this issue. One solution is to
>   use a software accelerated driver. To do it, in /etc/X11/xorg.conf,
>   look for the Section called Device and change the option Driver to
>   mesa.

I must edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, But there is no xorg.conf in `/etc/X11/` for me!

For this reason, through below command i've created xorg.conf : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

```
sudo service lightdm stop
Xorg -configure
```

Allright, I've copied `/home/xorg.conf` to `/etc/X11/`.

Also, According to following section of [above link](http://wiki.scilab.org/Graphical%20issues%20with%20Scilab%205.X) :

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Your Graphic card"
        Driver  "vesa"
[...]
EndSection
```

I must enter my graphic card model in `"Your Graphic card"` and also `"vesa"`. I don't know what exactly `vesa` is ! I've google it and someone said in [here](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/179672-Installing-OpenGL-mesa-on-ubuntu?p=1245516&viewfull=1#post1245516) for install `vesa` do below things and i did :

```
sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa && sudo apt-get install libosmesa6
```

After all the steps above, i have restart computer and then Ubuntu doesn't start up and stay on Black Screen !

Through LiveDisk I've boot Ubuntu, I guessed maybe it's because of `xorg.conf`, I removed that as the default and reboot again, Ubuntu does't start up again !

Comment: When you say you deleted `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, you mean you manually removed that file? I'm not trying to be negative or anything, but why did you do that? Was there some manual that told you so? As far as I know, mesa is a graphics library, and shouldn't have anything to do with your x11 install?

Comment: I'm newbie. Yes, I've manually removed that file. Look, It's complicated and long story why i manually removed that file. Look, my target was to update mesa and video card !

Comment: Look, just add this kind of information to the question, it'll help clear up what you are planning to do, and why you did certain things. It's easier to answer if we have all the information.

Comment: /etc/X11/xorg.conf isn't required anymore and can sometimes cause conflicting errors. It's common for instructions to tell you to delete it, specially when changing GL library versions.  @Hamed what instructions where you following what kind of card was it? Did you look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: First post has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me after I installed `libgles1-mesa`. It removed `ubuntu-desktop`, so I had to press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and reinstall it in tty1.

[Installing libgles1-mesa messes up my system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434913/installing-libgles1-mesa-messes-up-my-system)