# Unable to install Octave

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I am trying to install [Octave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave) by using these commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
```

But I am getting the following error message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 octave : Depends: libosmesa6 (>= 6.5.2-1) but it is not going to be installed or
                   libgl1-mesa-glide3 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I fix this problem?

Edit- Output for `apt-cache policy libosmesa6` –

```
libosmesa6:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4
  Version table:
     10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     10.1.0-4ubuntu5 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Edit2- Output for `apt-cache policy octave`

```
octave:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.0-3ubuntu2~octave~trusty1
  Version table:
     4.0.0-3ubuntu2~octave~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     3.8.1-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libosmesa6`

Comment: Start the command `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glide3` and add the output into your question.

Comment: @A.B. I have added the output in my question. Please have a look. Also, I would like to tell you I somehow installed `libosmesa6` but when I restarted my system, it started giving a blank screen. I ended up doing a fresh install of ubuntu. I later on read this `mesa` installation creates problems

Comment: @A.B. This is similar to what happened with me earlier-
http://askubuntu.com/questions/299543/after-installing-mesa-ubuntu-doesnt-start-up

Comment: yes my ubuntu is 14.04 .

Comment: Give me the output of `apt-cache policy octave`

Comment: @A.B.  Added the  output in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28836/discussion-between-a-b-and-noober).

Comment: I have added a summary in my answer taken from the chat. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is no universal answer. The problem was complex and was dissolved by a longer analysis in the chat.

Here is a summary from the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28836/conversation/unable-to-install-octave).

```
sudo apt-get install libosmesa6
sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa
```

It removed a lot of packages, eg `ubuntu-desktop`

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

From here, we used `aptitude`, a better problem resolver

```
sudo aptitude install libgl1-mesa-dri
```

Now a lot of packages was removed, but `ubuntu-desktop` is installed.

```
sudo aptitude install unity8
sudo aptitude install octave
```

Done

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me at the end on a Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit machine.

In terminal, install:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep octave
sudo apt-get install libqt4-opengl-dev
```

Then download and build Octave from source:

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-4.0.0.tar.xz
tar -xaf octave-4.0.0.tar.xz
cd octave-4.0.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

This worked on all the machines I tried in my laboratory.

Comment: Did u get GUI of octave-4.0.0 working?

Comment: Yes, So nice. Not one machine. On many machines now !

Comment: I cannot get the GUI to work. After installing from source what did u do to get the GUI to work?

Comment: (i) cd octave-4.0.0 (ii) ./run-octave. I am doing only the above steps and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep octave
```

This will install all dependencies for Octave,

refer [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Obtaining-the-Dependencies-Automatically.html#Obtaining-the-Dependencies-Automatically)

After that You can use what you followed for installation

**Or**

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:picaso/octave
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install octave
```

Refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194151/how-do-you-install-the-latest-version-of-gnu-octave)

Comment: note that this will use more space and that installing only what is in the dependency error is usually more productive

Comment: @David cole I tried your command and error : __The following packages have unmet dependencies: libosmesa6 : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.__

Comment: It means instead of adding each dependency it is better to have all dependencies,@DavidCole

Comment: -1 One doesn't need the *build* dependencies of a package to run the software of the binary package.