# Installation of libglew1.6-dev causes next reboot to result in black screen with blinking cursor.

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot

I'm just beginning to use Ubuntu and I don't understand a problem I've been having. It seems incredibly specific as I haven't been able to find anyone else with a similar issue so I was wondering if someone could help me figure out why my Ubuntu 12.04 installation boots to a black screen with a blinking cursor whenever I try to install libglew1.6-dev on Ubuntu.

My system is a dualboot system with Win8.1 and Ubuntu 12.04.

I've tried using this guide 
[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)
but to no avail.

Comment: It seems `ubuntu-desktop` is removed . (similar to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/670797/unable-to-install-octave/670984#670984)).Try this : Open tty (Ctrl + Alt + F1) , run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Thank you @Ravan . Unfortunately that didn't work. In fact, I couldn't get to tty from normal boot, I had to use the recovery mode option and choose Resume Normal Boot to get to tty. When I tried installing ubuntu-desktop, the next boot was the same blinking cursor on black background. I think you're right about the installation  uninstalling something. I used apt-get purge to remove libglew1.6-dev and it had no visible effect on the next boot. I just have no idea what to reinstall.